# Excel each worksheet memory usage using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, worksheet

I have an excel workbook which has 10 worksheets. I want to find out the memory used by each excel worksheet using Power-Shell. I tried to load Com object and checked the properties but no luck!

```
$application = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$wb=$application.workbooks.open("C:\Model_Q.xlsx")
$wb.sheets |gm
```

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you're looking for because it's not in PowerShell but I have found a pretty easy solution using VBA in Excel, and seeing as you have no answers right now, it's worth a shot! 
(1) Open up your worksheet in Excel and press Alt+F11, right click your Workbook and click Insert>Module.
(2) Paste in the following VBA script:

```
Sub WorksheetSizes()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xOutWs As Worksheet
Dim xOutFile As String
Dim xOutName As String
xOutName = "SheetSizesinBits"
xOutFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TempWb.xls"
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Err = 0
Set xOutWs = Application.Worksheets(xOutName)
If Err = 0 Then
    xOutWs.Delete
    Err = 0
End If
With Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Before:=Application.Worksheets(1))
    .Name = xOutName
    .Range("A1").Resize(1, 2).Value = Array("Worksheet Name", "Size")
End With
Set xOutWs = Application.Worksheets(xOutName)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
xIndex = 1
For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If xWs.Name <> xOutName Then
        xWs.Copy
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xOutFile
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Set Rng = xOutWs.Range("A1").Offset(xIndex, 0)
        Rng.Resize(1, 2).Value = Array(xWs.Name, VBA.FileLen(xOutFile))
        Kill xOutFile
        xIndex = xIndex + 1
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

(3) Save your workbook as a Macro Enabled Workbook.
(4) Close the developer screen and hit Alt+F8.
(5) Select the Macro we just made  and run it. 
This will create a new worksheet, and build a table of the size of each worksheet in bits.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way i can use it in powershell